How to simulate mouse drag by win32api.SendMessage in Python?
I try to simulate mouse drag operation by win32api.SendMessage in Python,
here is my code:
import win32api
...
lParam_start = win32api.MAKELONG(start[0], start[1])
lParam_end = win32api.MAKELONG(end[0] , end[1])

win32api.SendMessage(self.window.handle, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, lParam_start)
time.sleep(0.1)
win32api.SendMessage(self.window.handle, win32con.WM_MOUSEMOVE, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, lParam_end)
time.sleep(0.1)
win32gui.SendMessage(self.window.handle, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, lParam_end)
...

and Spy++ log message:

The actual situation seems to be that the mouse is not in LBUTTONDOWN state during movement.
I have tried replacing WM_LBUTTONUP with WM_MOUSELEAVE, still the same.
How to keep the LBUTTONDOWN state in WM_MOUSEMOVE? I know SendInput() is ok, but it can only be used in foreground mode.

You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage. Input messages are a result of input processing. Faking the messages doesn't magically go back in time to fake the per-thread input state to match. Whatever problem you are trying to solve this isn't going to be part of the solution.

Even though the article @IInspectable mentions is about the keyboard, the same issue applies to the mouse, too.

You may try simulating the same messages generated by the mouse drag If you do want. If it doesn't work, not surprising.

I think the foreground window will capture the mouse when the mouse left button is pressed, to instruct the system sending all subsequent mouse events to the window even if the mouse cursor has left. So i think when you are executing the simulation, you should never move your mouse nor release the mouse left button.
